# Advanced search in Multidomain - Multilanguage catalog webpage Drupal 7

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, search

I have a quite complex products database. I have migrated most of the content and hierarchy into Drupal taxonomy, content type and relationships scheme. However, I am not sure if I will be able to configure some Advanced search module to look for products according to name of product, category (taxonomy) and other intrincate parameters. Can you advice some module which is easy to configure and write own MySQL search strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least two options. You can use the Views module to expose search filters on the products.

If you have access to an Apache Solr search server you can use some of the modules that integrate with Solr for advanced searching.